# Simultaneously accessing(read/write) the file issue

Tags: php

I'm trying to understand something... Say I'm using some script that checks the `.txt` file and what's in it, and then depend on the value I get, I change the file's data accordingly. But the problem I have is: what if, for example, 100 000 people will access this file simultaneously? I mean the file should be locked while writing into it, so does it mean there will be some sort of a delay between this 100 000 people of accessing the file(writing into it)?

Comment: Yes there is a file lock and that can't be avoided :) . The delay is very small and there are other areas like db access or network latency that provide more delay. You should not be worried about locks on file for writing :)

Comment: A little of question above if the file is same maybe consider caching the same :)

Comment: @georoot, you mean that the "lock" it self is nothing to worry about, got it. But does this mean I should worry about other things while using this method(accessing the file) or not worry at all, bcause the delay of this kind of things is irrelevant?

Comment: Whether it causes noticeable delays depends on how long it takes the process to write data to it. And whether the o/s has to write it to disk immediately. I assume for a commonly shared file. 1) The amount of data is small 2) the normal operating system write defaults are used. So, it is unlikely to a significant bottleneck.